# Can't pass variable from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I want to load data from my MySQL server with php code and then use it to draw chart with google charts. the problem is that i can't use the data that quered from my mysql in the java-script code.

***PHP code***:

```
  $connection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','123456');
  mysql_select_db('db_statmarket',$connection);
  $result2 = mysql_query('select sum(`How much read from customer`) as Leads, Date from monitor group by Date;',$connection) or die('cannot show tables');
```

Here in the javascript code where we can see the `var data = ...` i want that he will be the table that i quered from my database.

***HTML & JS code***:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

The output need to be seen like these:
[image]

Comment: Either pass as javascript variable in page or use ajax. Not hard to do a web search for using either approach

Comment: @charlietfl hey charlie, how i pass $result2 as a variable?

Comment: $result2 cannot be use in javascript. It is raw SQL results, you must put them in an array using mysql_fetch_assoc() (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','123456');
    mysql_select_db('db_statmarket',$connection);
    $result2 = mysql_query('select sum(`How much read from customer`) as Leads, Date from monitor group by Date;',$connection) or die('cannot show tables');

    $json = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>;
    // chart code here
</script>
```

If your javascript is in a .js file, you can:

1. Make your *data* variable "global" (though it would be better to wrap it in a global object, in order to not pollute global namespace)
2. Use Ajax (in this case the php code would be identical, but in a separate file returning only JSON data)

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't work. It doesn't fir the 'var data' format table that written in HTML code.

Comment: You must adapt it to your needs. I cannot provide you with a complete copy/paste code without knowing more (and I don't actually think this is gonna help you). Just check the value of "data" and modify your sql request or javascript to fit your needs (first problem I see, you select 2 columns but want an output with 3 columns). You will also have to manually add to "data" the first entry (['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses']). Feel free to let me knowif you need more help.